# SQLite query between two set of elements

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two sets of elements A:[1,2,3,4] and B:[5,6,7,8] and I would like to know if it's possible to make a query to select all the stations that contain at least one element in A and one element in B

SELECT * FROM Stations WHERE myStation.lines correspond to at least one in A AND at least one in B

myStation.lines is also a set of elements...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please normalize your database design. (First normal form)

Comment: A and B are tables on your database?

Comment: myStation.lines, A and B are results of a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for this:

```
select * from Stations where lines IN 
(select distinct [column_name] from A) AND 
lines in (select distinct [column_name] from B)
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem in your example is that lines is a value but let say line is also a set like A and B???

Comment: @ncohen So, in essence, A and B are just a one-row table and Stations is a multi-row table?

Comment: I finnaly found a workaround by merging tables and testing each value with the IN function... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL do this if there exists a function that will conduct the set operation in some WHERE clause. For what I know sqlite *doesn't* have such functions, but you can always [create a user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html). Otherwise, you should normalize your data so that one record holds one value (only one of 1,2,3,4,....) and then you can join.